# How to filter dates in flexgrid from Wijmo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wijmo

Is anyone here familiar with Wijmo? I am new to it and currently using it's free version, the Wijmo 5. I want to filter the Flexgrid every time a change event occurs on my datepicker. A FlexGrid is similar to the JQuery plugin DataTable, but I am required to work on Wijmo. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the filter on the underlying CollectionView based on the value selected via datepicker. Here is a similar sample demonstrating how you can filter FlexGrid as you type in TextBox :
http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/FlexGridIntro/FlexGridIntro/

Comment: I have been to that page, however, Im not using Angular but pure JS and just found the solution there int their examples (D'oh). Thanks anyway!

Comment: We do have PureJS sample as well. Here is the link: http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/PureJS/FlexGridIntro/FlexGridIntro/